# Why reading Text with Emgu CV OCR Tesseract works while Tesseract.NET doesn't

Tags: c#, ocr

Emgu Cv library has a namespace for using the Optical Character Recognition algorithms that can be used to detect text on a sample image. I have to give credit to Emgu Cv for this, their software works for almost any type of image as long as it contains text. Even if the text is embedded as part of the background. Now here is where am confused. We initialize Emgu Cv Ocr Tesseract engine the same way we initialize the engine for Tesseract.NET, except that Tesseract.NET doesn't recognize text on any of the images where Emgu Cv Ocr Tesseract managed read text from. The parameters to the constructors are the same and they both rely on a folder with the trained data for the language of the text on the image.
Here is how am using Emgu Cv Ocr to read text from an image

```
//import Emgu CV Ocr types
using Emgu.CV.Ocr.Tesseract;

//create a new engine of the later
var tesseract = new Tesserract("./tessdata","eng",EngineMode.Default);
//define the image to read text from
Mat mat = new Mat("image.png");
//set an image for the engine
tesseract.SetImage(mat);
//recognize the text
tesseract.Recognize();
//get the text
string result = tesseract.GetText();
```

Now the other counter part is the original Tesseract.NET library whose engine gets instantiated like below

```
using Tesseract;
var engine = new TesserractEngine("./tessdata","eng",EngineMode.Default);
var page = Pix.LoadFromFile("image.png");
//get the text 
var res = engine.Process(page);
var str = res.GetText();
```

For some reason the original Tesseract.NET library doesn't work but Emfu Cv Ocr Tesseract works which i can see uses the logic of the old library to create an instance of an engine, why is this?